# Traffic from traffic exchange redirect to my website

Tags: redirects, google-adsense, web-traffic, website-promotion

When you are using Google AdSense to profit from your website, and you use Traffic Exchange Google will ban you, but I was just thinking: 
 Let's say I have website A and website B. I will use traffic exchange on the site A and the A there will be auto-redirect(or pop-up) to the site B where I want the traffic to have on AdSense.

1. When I will do this will Google ban it even if it sees that the traffic is coming from website A?
2. What would be the consequences for the website A if Google finds it?
3. What would be the consequences for the website B if Google finds it?
4. What would be the consequences for my Google AdSense if Google finds it?

Just to inform: I am not trying to cheat on Google or even contemplate it.
I have enough views on my website. It was just an idea because if someone uses that it would be unfair for us.

Comment: Are you asking us to help you cheat Google? Or even contemplate it? Seriously??

Comment: No ofc not...I have enough views on my website. It was just an idea because if someone uses that it would be unfair for us

Comment: They would be caught. The request header would give them away.

Comment: For the record, your question reads like you are looking to scam someone. You may want to edit it. Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdSense will ban you, if traffic quality is not good at all, that's simple reason is apply to all website.

They have solid algorithm to identify such a quality traffic, for example if I visit your website A, then I will redirect or open pop up on my browser, then AdSense will see this is some kind of referral traffic from website A. If I do nothing and just closing the webpage, then such a webpage is consider as low quality webpage.

When you use pop up, AdSense will know that the traffic come from some mini window tab, and when you use redirects script, then they will get information from browser header tags.

If you buy cheap traffic then AdSense might consider those clicks are invalid because they have no more data to identify weather clicks are valid or invalid, so AdSense generally works great for organic traffic.